# Domain query not returning results

Tags: apex

I have a registered Domain, but yet when I want to query it, it does not return any results. If I query sites, I can get the SubDomains.
The query I use is
Select Domain from Domain

Comment: Not sure if querrying site will help.
Select id,name,Subdomain,Status,UrlPathPrefix from Site

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am able to retrieve data, but unfortunately what I need is the Domain Name. When i query the domain, no results are being returned, but yet I do have enabled domain in Salesforce.